# set bitmap image to main window background

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to set an image to background to the main windows of my win32 application, I'm trying to set in in the main function  `wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW);`

---

```
WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW);
```

but I can't find the correct syntax??

Answer (score 1):

```
wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
```

is the correct syntax.  To set an image as window background, you can use:

```
hbr=CreatePatternBrush(LoadBitmap(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BGROUND)));
wcex.hbrBackground = bhr
```

If you prefer to control the drawing, you can handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` and draw your image in this function and then return non-zero for the `DefWindowProc` to ignore this message.